# ServiceTalk gRPC error code mapping for StreamingHttpServiceFilter

Tags: java, grpc, servicetalk

We have implemented `StreamingHttpServiceFilter` which performs authentication on each request.

On unsuccessful authentication, we return 401 Unauthorized error by using following code:

```html
private StreamingHttpResponse createUnauthorizedResponse(final StreamingHttpResponseFactory responseFactory) {
        return responseFactory.unauthorized();
    }
```

When the filter return an error, on client side we are getting following message

> GrpcStatus{code=INTERNAL, cause=null, description='HTTP status code:
> 401 Unauthorized  invalid content-type: null  headers:
> NettyH2HeadersToHttpHeaders[transfer-encoding: ]'}

As you see GrpcStatus has `code=INTERNAL`, which means client needs to parse the `description`, and figure out the error code.

Is it possible to add any additional metadata while preparing the response from filter so that code can be `UNAUTHENTICATED` or is there any client side util available which reads the description and convert into http status code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gRPC protocol does not pay much attention to HTTP response status code, it always expects `200 OK`. Other status codes will be mapped to `INTERNAL` gRPC code. Instead, it relies on `grpc-status` and `grpc-message` that come as trailers (or headers when there is no payload body) of the HTTP/2 response message. See [Responses](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-HTTP2.md#responses) section in gRPC over HTTP2 doc.

When you are at HTTP level and writing an `StreamingHttpServiceFilter`, you are responsible for generating a response according to the gRPC protocol. The minimal response is `Trailers-Only` and contains `HTTP-Status Content-Type Status [Status-Message] *Custom-Metadata`.

For the described use-case, it should be easy to generate an appropriate response manually.

Alternative approach is to throw a `GrpcStatusException` from gRPC level: from the service endpoint or from a gRPC-filter. Then ServiceTalk will map that exception to an appropriate HTTP/2 response with all required header fields.

```
// Throws GrpcStatusException:
throw new GrpcStatus(GrpcStatusCode.UNAUTHENTICATED, null, "Your message for the client")
        .asException();
```

However, in your case, you may have additional complexity of transferring auth information from `StreamingHttpServiceFilter` level to gRPC-filter via `AsyncContext`. May not worth it.